# i'm trying implement ng-autocomplete in my ionic4 page

Tags: ionic4

```
  <ion-input placeholder="Address" style="margin:10px">
                <ng-autocomplete
                        [(ngModel)]="userData.address"
                        [searchKeyword]="'name'"
                        [data]="suggestions"
                        (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
                        (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
                        [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
                        [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
                </ng-autocomplete>
            </ion-input>
```

how can i make the autocomplete work in my page.
this is on location input for the user.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you edit your question and add the page's component.ts code as well?

Comment: the actual problem i have is that it doesn't show in broswser and i tried to inspect that ion-auto-complete element, it does show on the element inspection.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need to add the AutocompleteLibModule to the component's module imports array.

Below is an implementation in ionic of the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-autocomplete) example found on the package's [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete) page that you can use for reference.

`home.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AutocompleteLibModule } from 'angular-ng-autocomplete';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ]),
    AutocompleteLibModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

`home.page.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor() { }

  keyword = 'name';
  public countries = [
    {      id: 1,      name: 'Albania',    },
    {      id: 2,      name: 'Belgium',    },
    {      id: 3,      name: 'Denmark',    },
    {      id: 4,      name: 'Montenegro',    },
    {      id: 5,      name: 'Turkey',    },
    {      id: 6,      name: 'Ukraine',    },
    {      id: 7,      name: 'Macedonia',    },
    {      id: 8,      name: 'Slovenia',    },
    {      id: 9,      name: 'Georgia',    },
    {      id: 10,      name: 'India',    },
    {      id: 11,      name: 'Russia',    },
    {      id: 12,      name: 'Switzerland',    }
  ];
  selectEvent(item) {
    // do something with selected item
  }

  onChangeSearch(search: string) {

    // fetch remote data from here
    // And reassign the 'data' which is binded to 'data' property.
  }

  onFocused(e) {
    // do something
  }

 }
```

`home.page.html`

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">

  <div>
    <ng-autocomplete 
      [data]="countries" 
      [searchKeyword]="keyword" 
      placeHolder="Enter the Country Name"
      (selected)='selectEvent($event)' 
      (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)' 
      (inputFocused)='onFocused($event)'
      historyIdentifier="countries" 
      [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate" 
      [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
    </ng-autocomplete>

    <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
      <a [innerHTML]="item.name"></a>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
      <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

Hope this helps.